# nodejs express session error

Tags: node.js, session, express

I wrote a demo website with nodejs. In file `app.js` I used `express.session`

Case 1:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser())
app.use(express.session({    secret: "whatever"   }));  
//this code is working
```

Case 2:

```
app.use(express.session({    secret: "whatever"   }));   
app.use(express.cookieParser());
//this is not correct
```

The error log is:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined
at Object.session [as handle] (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:239:32)
at next (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.favicon [as handle] (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\favicon.js:77:7)
at next (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.handle (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express-partials\index.js:94:5)
at next (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.expressInit [as handle] (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5)
at next (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.query [as handle] (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:44:5)
at next (D:\web\nodejs\Weibo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware order matter in Express, as they are executed in the order you defined them. In your case, the `cookieParser` middleware adds some information that is used by the `session` middleware.

You can check [connect's documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html#session):

> Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, however
>   cookies are used, so we must use the cookieParser()
>   middleware before session().