# node js Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined

Tags: node.js, session, express, server

hello i have noode js server project
and i am trying to work with session using this tutorial
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local
and i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;connect.sid&#39; of undefined
    at Layer.session [as handle] (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express-session\index.js:115:32)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
    at C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)
    at Context.next (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19)
    at Context.actions.pass (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\context\http\actions.js:77:8)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\strategies\session.js:67:10)
    at attempt (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\middleware\authenticate.js:243:16)
    at Passport.authenticate (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\middleware\authenticate.js:244:7)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
    at C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19)
    at Passport.initialize (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\middleware\initialize.js:69:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
    at C:\Users\Erez\node\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
```

here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'iloveschocolate'})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001; 


// middleware to use for all requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // do logging
    next();
});

require('./Controllers/routes.js')(app, passport); 

app.listen(port);
console.log('see whats happening on port ' + port);
```

i have tried many answers and nothing helped me
i have try this [Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined at Layer.session - ExpressJS session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107414/cannot-read-property-connect-sid-of-undefined-at-layer-session-expressjs-ses)
and this [Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined at Layer.session - ExpressJS session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107414/cannot-read-property-connect-sid-of-undefined-at-layer-session-expressjs-ses)
and this [nodejs express session error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355965/nodejs-express-session-error)
and also this document about connect - http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html#session

when i remove this line `app.use(session({ secret: 'iloveschocolate',})); // session secret` it works but it all the point to use this session? if i am right

i am using express 4 so i cant add express.cookie-parser
thanks for the helpers

Comment: why is that `,` there after ilovechoclate? Just curious.

Comment: by mistake here edited

Comment: I am confused. Where is `connect.sid` part?

Comment: is a default key for session

Answer (score 1):

maybe because you haven't use your cookieparser , before initialize()

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, however cookies are used, so we must use the cookieParser() middleware before session().

Answer (score 0):

Try placing cookieParser before session :

```
app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(session(
      {
        secret: 'appsecretkey',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
          secure: true,
          maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
        }
      }));
```